# Spark to kafka connection using ssl connection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ssl, hive, apache-kafka

I am trying to publish the data to kafka topic in cloud from spark data frame on perm. to connect i have ssl certificates(trust store,key-store).
but i don't know how to connect using the certificates in Scala intellij.
sample code will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is same as making any other SSL connection.
Import your cert in keystore and refer to that key store using below code

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "keystoreFilefullpath")
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password")
```

Once these params are set then Kafka SSL should work.
If you are publishing from Spark then keystore file must be uploaded to driver/executor using **--files** option